# Async version of once_cell, or a way to avoid error[E0744]: `.await` is not allowed in a `static`?

Tags: rust, lazy-evaluation, rust-sqlx

I've been using `once_cell` to do a lot of work that only needs to be done once, and then persist as read-only global. This is nice because I don't have to pass these things around. I was wanting to know if something like this is permitted for db handles/pools?

```rust
static POOL: Pool<Postgres> = PgPoolOptions::new()
    .max_connections(5)
    .connect("postgres://postgres:password@localhost/test")
    .await
    .unwrap();
```

But alas, this doesn't work because of the `.await`,

```
error[E0744]: `.await` is not allowed in a `static`
  --> src/main.rs:10:31
```

And, if I try to wrap in `once_cell`, I get

```
static POOL = Lazy::new(|| sqlx_rt::block_on(
  PgPoolOptions::new()
      .max_connections(5)
      .connect("postgres://postgres:password@localhost/test")
      .await
) );
```

Is there anyway to do what I want here

Comment: it would be possible to have static where each time you want access them you need to be in a async context but... I think the good way would be to make your singleton yourself by calling the init yourself in a async fn main

Answer (score 4):

### Tokio OnceCell (added in Tokio 1.5.0 released April 12, 2021)

Tokio now provides an async OnceCell, [tokio::sync::OnceCell](http://docs.rs/tokio/1.27.0/tokio/sync/struct.OnceCell.html)! You can use the Tokio OnceCell for async code.

---

### Using the once_cell crate (early 2021 answer)

The `once_cell` crate does not [currently provide](https://github.com/matklad/once_cell/issues/108) an async API. Instead, you can initialize the static from your main function:

```rust
static POOL: OnceCell<String> = OnceCell::new();

#[rt::main]
async fn main() {
    let pg_pool = PgPoolOptions::new()
        .max_connections(5)
        .connect("postgres://postgres:password@localhost/test")
        .await
        .unwrap();
    POOL.set(pg_pool).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: UPDATE: Tokio now provides an async OnceCell! Yay! https://docs.rs/tokio/1.27.0/tokio/sync/struct.OnceCell.html (It was actually being developed and prepped for release right around the time this answer was posted in April 2021.)